# XSLT transform to search and delete

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

The `<P1>` tags appear under `<web-app>` and under `<servlet>` tags in the XML file. 
I want to search `<servlet>` tag with `<servlet-name>` as DUMMY and then delete `<P1>` tags under it when its sub-tag `<p1-name>` is equal to B2 OR B3. We DO NOT WANT TO ALTER THE `<P1>` tags directly uder `<web-app>`

I have got familiar with identity template and searching but struggling to delete. Any solutions so that i can tackle similar problems in future?

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true">

<P1>IGNORE1</P1>
<P1>IGNORE2</P1>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TEST</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.TEST</servlet-class>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>A1</p1-name>
            <p1-value>A11111</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>A2</p1-name>
            <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>A3</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>A4</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>A5</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>

      <junk>1</junk>
  </servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DUMMY</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.DUMMY</servlet-class>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>B1</p1-name>
            <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>B2</p1-name>
            <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>B3</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>B4</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>B5</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>

      <junk>1333</junk>
  </servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SAMMY</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.SAMMY</servlet-class>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>C1</p1-name>
            <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>C2</p1-name>
            <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>C3</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>C4</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>
        <P1>
            <p1-name>C5</p1-name>
                <p1-value/>
        </P1>

      <junk>12313</junk>
  </servlet>


<D>
        <D1>
            <D11>admin</D11>            
        </D1>
        <D2>
            <D21>XX</D21>
        </D2>
</D>

<E>
     <E1>Yo</E1>
     <E2>Hello</E2>
</E>

</web-app>
```

The O/P XML should look like this where `<P1>` tag under `<servlet>` with `<servlet-name>` as DUMMY are removed because `<p1-name>` was either B2 OR B3.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app metadata-complete="true">
  <P1>IGNORE1</P1>
  <P1>IGNORE2</P1> 


        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TEST</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.TEST</servlet-class>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>A1</p1-name>
                <p1-value>A11111</p1-value>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>A2</p1-name>
                <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>A3</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>A4</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>A5</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>

          <junk>1</junk>
      </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DUMMY</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.DUMMY</servlet-class>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>B1</p1-name>
                <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
            </P1>


            <P1>
                <p1-name>B4</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>B5</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>

          <junk>1333</junk>
      </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SAMMY</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.SAMMY</servlet-class>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>C1</p1-name>
                <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>C2</p1-name>
                <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>C3</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>C4</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>
            <P1>
                <p1-name>C5</p1-name>
                    <p1-value/>
            </P1>

          <junk>12313</junk>
      </servlet>


    <D>
            <D1>
                <D11>admin</D11>            
            </D1>
            <D2>
                <D21>XX</D21>
            </D2>
    </D>

    <E>
         <E1>Yo</E1>
         <E2>Hello</E2>
    </E>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation and an empty template for the elements you want to remove:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="servlet[servlet-name = 'DUMMY']/P1[p1-name = ('B2', 'B3')]"/>
```

At http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4ki I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true">
   <P1>IGNORE1</P1>
   <P1>IGNORE2</P1>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TEST</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.TEST</servlet-class>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>A1</p1-name>
         <p1-value>A11111</p1-value>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>A2</p1-name>
         <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>A3</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>A4</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>A5</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <junk>1</junk>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>DUMMY</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.DUMMY</servlet-class>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>B1</p1-name>
         <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>B4</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>B5</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <junk>1333</junk>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>SAMMY</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.mm.bb.servlet.SAMMY</servlet-class>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>C1</p1-name>
         <p1-value>B11111</p1-value>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>C2</p1-name>
         <p1-value>A22222</p1-value>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>C3</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>C4</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <P1>
         <p1-name>C5</p1-name>
         <p1-value/>
      </P1>
      <junk>12313</junk>
   </servlet>
   <D>
      <D1>
         <D11>admin</D11>
      </D1>
      <D2>
         <D21>XX</D21>
      </D2>
   </D>
   <E>
      <E1>Yo</E1>
      <E2>Hello</E2>
   </E>
</web-app>
```

Comment: But how will these get rid of P1 with p1-name as B2 and B3? The above XSLT doesnt seem to work on the I/P XML i shared to produce the O/P xml

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I had some IDE issue which was behaving erratically earlier. All good now. Works as charm.

Comment: @TestUser: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.